# How to see rectangular marquee selected area size without cropping it ? in photoshop cs 5

Tags: photoshop, selected, marquee, dimension

How can i see rectangular marquee selected area size without cropping it ? It is very easy in paint.net but i have to do in photoshop cs 5. While selecting an area i should be able to see the dimensions of selected area. How can i do that ?

Also when i select an area with rectangular marquee i want to see the position of that area or at least i need to be able to see a pixel position. Position means its position in the image like top 55px left 45px thank you.

Adobe Photoshop CS 5

Comment: This question is not a Stack Overflow question. It belongs into Graphic Design Stack Exchange.

Comment: This question is about graphics software usage. It belongs to Graphic Design Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The cursor position and selection size are shown in the Info window (F8, in the upper right in my workspace).

Answer (score 47):

Edit -> Preferences -> Units & Rulers... -> Set Rulers to Pixels

Comment: On a Mac : Photoshop -> Preferences -> Units & Rulers... -> Set Rulers to Pixels

Comment: Yes, but still simple would be. **Ctrl+R** (Brings your rulers) and then **Right Click over the ruler** and Select whatever you prefer